# CKeditor & KCFinder in localhost

Tags: windows, image, upload, ckeditor, local

I am a building a website locally and I am using CKeditor with KCFinder at a part of it. CKEditor runs properly and KCFinder Upload Tab is also visible, so I guess my installation was correct.

BUT! When I try to upload an image using the KCFinder module ("Browse" then "Send to server") I get an error message showing in the same popped-up window saying:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
03/01/12 14:31:05
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8
```

I have Windows 7, running it in localhost with Easy PHP and the local path to my target folder is:

```
C:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~2.1\www\electro\kcfinder\upload
```

In my kcfinder/config.php I have:

```
    'uploadURL' => "/upload",
    'uploadURL' => "../upload",
    'uploadDir' => "",
    'uploadDir' => "C:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~2.1\www\electro\kcfinder\upload",
```

as instructed by [the official related thread here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/kcfinder/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=73).

Anyone has any idea what might be wrong?

**EDIT:** 
Solved it. Needed to change the paths on both KCFinder/config.php AND CKEditor/config.js. Since my paths are:

The project path:

```
C:\PROGRA~2\EASYPH~2.1\www\electro
```

and it has the subfolders "ckeditor" and "kcfinder" and I want to have the folder "kcfinder/upload" as the target folder of the filed to be uploaded, then the following changes need to made...

ckeditor/config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '../electro/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '../electro/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '../electro/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../electro/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '../electro/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '../electro/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
};
```

kcfinder/config.php:

```
'uploadURL' => "upload",
'uploadDir' => "",
```

For some reason it needed the ../ while it was already in the same folder. I don't understand why, but it works.

Now, I would like to say how displeased I am at the developer of the KCFinder where people with the same issue or others on its support forum the given "help" was things like "RTFM", "Do better searches" etc. As if everyone was born an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 3):

I actually found the answer shortly after I posted my answer. It seems that the path system on ckeditor/config.js doesn't really work as a normal path usually works. so, you have to play around with the "../" and try to find out where it is aiming at. In my case, I didn't need any "../" to refer to a file that was in a separated folder one level up. So the final code for me was:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
   config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
   config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
   config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
};
```

when actually should be '../kcfinder/browse.php?type=files'

Hope it helps...